# Error when extending a magento block

Tags: magento, block, extend

I'm trying to extend the defult magento welcome msg block, however I am met with an error:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Block_Page_Html_Welcome' in /var/www/magento/project/app/Mage.php:595

Here's the relevant part of config xml for my module:

```
<config>
    <!-- -->
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_welcome>ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Block_Page_Html_Welcome</html_welcome>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And here's the extended class located in

> /app/code/local/ModuleNameSpace/Modulename/Page/Block/Html/Welcome.php

```
<?php
class ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Page_Block_Html_Welcome extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome
{

}
?>
```

Should any other information be required, just tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the class name of your block. i.e.,

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <modulename>
            <class>Mynamespace_Modulename_Block</class>
        </modulename>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

then you can call your block like

```
<block type="modulename/some" template="some.phtml">
```

### Edit

> /app/code/local/ModuleNameSpace/Modulename/Page/Block/Html/Welcome.php

Change your folder structure like this

> /app/code/local/ModuleNameSpace/Modulename/Block/Page/Html/Welcome.php

add change the class name

```
<?php
class ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Block_Page_Html_Welcome extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome
{
}
?>
```

Comment: change your class name in like ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Block_Page_Html_Welcome

Comment: After changing the folder structure and class name, the error changed to ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Block_Html_Welcome . It's progress I guess :)
edit: changing class name to random nonsense results in fatal error - Fatal error: Class 'ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Block_Page_Html_Welcome' not found in /var/www/project/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491

Comment: Try changing your structure name to something `Namespace_Modulename`

Comment: @user2606641 Is this class inheritance of `Mage_Core_Block_Template`? which is necessary..

Comment: @user2606641 your module may not be active.

Comment: please check your `app/etc/modules/ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName.xml`

Comment: @Mr_Green yes it inherits from Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome which in turn inherits from Mage_Core_Block_Template.
@ Meenakshi Sundaram R It is enabled, double checked

Comment: It worked finally, when I used <block type=page/html_welcome"> Thanks everyone for helping me correct the errors that I had!

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to magento add  module namespace.....

Your Module structure is wrong
You module like

```
local>ModulennamesSpace>ModuleName>
```

And config.xml path is  `local>ModulennamesSpace>ModuleName>etc>config.xml`

```
<config>
    <!-- -->
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_welcome>ModuleNameSpace_Modulename_Block_Page_Html_Welcome</html_welcome>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: I joined the namespace and modulename together in the provided code, sorry if that made it unclear, it's edited now.